# How to make executable file that can run on on other operating system as well?

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, pyinstaller

I made an entire application with python using tkinter GUI, so for distribution I converted in executable file using pyinstaller. My problem is this exe only runs on Win10(i.e. my OS) but the clients might use any other OS such as Mac or any other windows 32bit. I want to make an exe file that can run on respective OS.

Comment: by exe I meant to say executable file not the .exe extension

Answer (score 3):

Different operating systems, all require their own custom executable formats to execute a program similar to a `.exe` on windows. That is the main reason why most software distributions are available separately for different operating systems, a separate file for mac, separate one for linux, etc..

So, there is no such thing as a cross platform single executable format, rather you would have to compile separate distributions for different operating systems.

The operating systems mentioned in the OP, have the following executable formats -:

- Mac - [MACH-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)
- Windows(Most versions, both 32 and 64 bit) -: This seemed to be an inconsistency with the question, as both 64 and 32 bit windows supports the `.exe` format, but in the question `.exe` was mentioned to not be functioning on the 32 bit version. - [.EXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.EXE)

For a list of executable formats mapped with operating system names refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats).

For all these executable formats there may or may not exist a builder similar to [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/) for .exe files, but one useful resource might be the [macholib](https://macholib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module, it can help deal with the executable format of mac from within python.

---

**EDIT:** Also even though not mentioned in the OP, since linux is a widely chosen operating system specially for programmers, it goes by the [`.ELF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file format. This might be helpful to any future visitors of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother this helped me. The first thing I would do after gaining reputation would be none other than upvoting this answer.

Comment: @AyanKhan No problem, My pleasure! and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also, I recently came across a few other ways of compiling python files to executable including even ways to convert to MACH-O files(py2app)! So I might as well add it into the answer as well, incase it might be helpful to you and other future visitors.